# Angular2,3,4 observable return true false after resolve service

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is return observable I want true or false to resolve my children routes

```
canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.isEmailExtends(childRoute);
}
isEmailExtends(ActivatedRouteSnapshot):Observable<boolean> {
     let email = "harishverma555@gmail.com";
     return this.userService.verifyUsername(email).pipe(
         map(response => {
             return true;
         }),
         catchError((error) => {
             return of(false);
         }));

}
```

}

Comment: Can you please explain what your question is?

Comment: @watercolour my question is simple I want to return this.isEmailExtends(childRoute);  this true or false

Comment: What is the problem? Is this not working? If not what is happening? Did you try to debug? If so how? What did you observe?

Comment: @Igor thanks for your response.
when i log this i got instead true false returns  "Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: CatchOperator}"

Comment: Where exactly are you logging this out? If you log it outside a subscribe or similar it will log out the observable, not the value. Overall this guard method seems fine as in its returning an Observale<boolean>

Comment: If you want use a Angular CanActivate guard, if return false, you use, before return false a router.navigate(['/yourPath']) and the function is canActivate. If you has a service, it's ok your code. Only remember **subscribe** in ngOnInit

Comment: Thanks, @Eliseo can we add the path( router.navigate(['/yourPath'])) before true 
like ` map(response => {
              router.navigate(['/yourPath']) 
             return true;
         }),`